# Error while using the recursive inclusion of Qt headers

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have big project in which appeared extremely incomprehensible mistake, after which I created a new project repeated it:

struct of project is simple:

> main.cpp
>       first.h
>       second.h

first.h

```
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

#include "second.h"

class first
{
public:
    first();
};

#endif // FIRST_H
```

second.h

```
#ifndef SECOND_H
#define SECOND_H

#include "first.h"

class second
{
public:
    second();
};

#endif // SECOND_H
```

Everything is quite logical, but Qt Creator thinks quite differently:

```
D:\WinFiles\Documents\QT\DELME1\DELME1\second.h:1: error: unterminated conditional directive
```

I am a bit at a loss case as for inheritance this construction is needed

Comment: #ifndef FIRST_H #define FIRST_H #endif // FIRST_H should solve this problem. Or not?

Comment: No, Include guards don't solve the circular include problem.

Comment: I have no dependencies in classes, only the inclusion of one file in another.

Comment: You have dependencies, Class `first` depends on `second` and class `second` depends on `first`. Please take a look at duplicate link, should solve your problem.

Comment: Don't understand anything! Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 compiled this code and did not find anything strange in it: **========== Build: successful: 1, with errors: 0, no change: 0, skipped: 0 ==========**

Comment: Does this mean it's time to change the compiler to MSVC Compiller?)

Comment: A cool situation happens when you learn C ++ at one compiler, and then you compile code under another and everything crashed.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem solving for MinGW compiler:

```
//first.h
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

class second;
class first
{
public:
    first();
};

#endif // FIRST_H

//second.h
#ifndef SECOND_H
#define SECOND_H

class first;
class second
{
public:
    second();
};

#endif // SECOND_H
```

> The second solution is to use MSVC compiller for qt which will guess what needs to be
>   done by itself and compiled all of the examples correctly.